# How do you cast a class to its subclass in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I come from a Java background, where classes which extend (inherit from) other classes are often passed around as the super class. I was hoping to do something similar in C++, but I have never worked with C++ inheritance before. I currently have the following:

```
class Obstacle{
    double get_position(){return position;}
};

class Wall : public Obstacle {
    double get_normal(){return normal;}
};
```

Obstacles, in general, can be any shape, but Walls are rectangular and therefore have an easily designed normal, which would not be appropriate for most Obstacles to have. However, another class has an aggregated `std::vector<Obstacle*>` which contains all Obstacles. When iterating through these Obstacles and doing calculations, I need to do separate calculations for separate types of Obstacles (there's a `get_type()` function in the superclass as well). When I have a Wall, I'd like to be able to call `get_normal()`, but if I try `static_cast<Wall>(current_obstacle)->get_normal()` I get the compilation error: `no matching function call to Wall(Obstacle*&)`. It also gives the same error if I use `((Wall)current_obstacle)->get_normal()`. It seems as though I should make a `Wall` constructor which takes an `Obstacle` and creates a new `Wall` object, but these doesn't seem to make sense to me.

In Java, I can cast any class to its subclass using `((Wall)current_obstacle).get_normal()`. Is this possible in C++ as well? Do I have to create a constructor? Thanks in advance. Sorry for my lack of understanding.

Comment: This one deals with all the ways you can use to cast an instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if `current_obstacle` is of type `Obstacle*`, then you should be casting it to `Wall*`. Currently you're trying to convert a pointer into a new object, which doesn't work.

Second, consider using `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`. This will check whether the object pointed to is really of type `Wall`, and if not, will return a null pointer. `static_cast` does not check, and undefined behaviour (read: Bad Things) will happen if your `Obstacle*` doesn't really point to a `Wall` but you cast it and call a `Wall` member function. (Casting in Java always performs this check for you, as you know.)

Comment: The `dynamic_cast` behavior described only works for polymorphic types (those that have virtual member functions)

Comment: True enough. `Obstacle` should have its destructor declared virtual, given the way it's being used (i.e. polymorphically)

Comment: Can you explain what a virtual destructor does? From my understanding, the `virtual` keyword is used to allow you to redefine a method in a subclass. Why would my destructor be virtual? I am not redefining it in my subclass.

Comment: @Teofrostus Every class has a destructor which cleans up its members, and if you don't provide one the compiler does.

Answer (score 2):

```
static_cast<Wall>(current_obstacle)->get_normal()
```

Try

```
static_cast<Wall*>(current_obstacle)->get_normal()
```

Comment: Oh. Wow. That was simple.